# How to find a substring skipping N chars

Tags: string, go

How do I get the index of a substring in a string skipping starting with a certain position/with a certain offset, e.g.:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    string := "something.value=something=end"
    index1 := strings.Index(string, "value=")
    fmt.Println(index1) // prints 10
    // index2 = ... How do I get the position of the second =, 25?
}
```

Similar offset in PHP `int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

Comment: Just subslice the string.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://play.golang.org/p/_J_APWXLMD5) could help, but I don't really know what your expecting result is. Do you want to know the position of each `=` in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package does not provide you such function, but in practice it's rarely needed. Often the [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) function is used to easily split strings into tokens / parts.

But if you do need it: you can simply [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) a `string`, which is efficient (no copy is made, the result shares memory with the original `string` value).

So effectively the function you're looking for would look like this:

```
func Index(s, substr string, offset int) int {
    if len(s) < offset {
        return -1
    }
    if idx := strings.Index(s[offset:], substr); idx >= 0 {
        return offset + idx
    }
    return -1
}
```

Example using it:

```
s := "something.value=something=end"
index1 := strings.Index(s, "value=")
fmt.Println(index1) // prints 10

index2 := Index(s, "=", index1+len("value="))
fmt.Println(index2) // prints 25
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gsMtHTN2PLr)):

```
10
25
```

Note that when slicing a string, and the `offset` you have to pass to our `Index()` function is the byte index, not the `rune` (character) index. They are equal as long as you have characters with less than `128` codepoints, but beyond that the byte index will be greater than the `rune` index because those codepoints map to multiple bytes in UTF-8 encoding (which is how Go stores strings in memory). `strings.Index()` returns you the byte index, and `len(s)` also returns you the byte-length, so the example will work with all strings properly.

Your original task using `strings.Split()` could look like this:

```
s := "something.value=something=end"
parts := strings.Split(s, "=")
fmt.Println(parts)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OAzxbhnzh5-)):

```
[something.value something end]
```

The value you want to "parse" out is in `parts[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

taking a slice of string with utf-8 characters may produce corrupted strings as you need to convert it to runes

`[]rune(videoHtml)[0:index`]